# Как можно делать запросы в sql в джава с переменными

Tags: java, sql

```
public int isInfod(Vacancy vacancy, String table, String collumn) {
    try (PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT ID FROM ? WHERE ? = ?")) {
                statement.setString(1, table);
                statement.setString(2, collumn);
                statement.setString(3, vacancy.getAuthor());
                statement.executeQuery();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
return 0;
```

такой запрос выдаёт ошибки , т.е. мне получается надо писать отдельный запрос под каждую таблицу и колонку? у меня же по сути запрос один и тотже ,

Comment: Имя таблицы нельзя задавать подстановочными символами.

Comment: Да и имя поля - тоже нельзя. Возможно использовать процедуру с prepared statement, конечно - но при этом требуется проверка переменных table и collumn на валидность (запросом в схему). *у меня же по сути запрос один и тотже* из 4 изменяемых характеристик запроса только одна постоянна, а три изменяются... очень странное понимание выражения "один и тот же"...

Comment: Необходимость подобного часто сигнализирует об архитектурных проблемах.

Comment: Можно и не отдельный. Запрос в данном случае обычная строка, значит ее можно собрать из частей. Только надо не забыть проверить что в именах таблиц и колонок не оказалось недопустимых символов, которые поломают запрос

Comment: Получается, что все ваши запросы прибиты гвоздями к некоему типу `Vacancy`. У вас в _каждой_ таблице есть поле, где хранится `Author`?